# How to read a text file (each individual item on its own line) into a 2D list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to read a text file into a 2D list in Python.
"people2.txt" is single lines in sequence (each item on its own line)

```
fred
23
ann
27
bob
24
```

Code so far:

```
details_list=[]

people2=open("people2.txt","r")

for line in people2.readlines():
    details_list.append(line.split())

people2.close()

print(details_list)
```

What I'm getting is each element in its own list, when I need "pairs"? I'm getting

```
[["fred"],["23"],["ann"],["27"],["bob"],["24"]]
```

What I need is:

```
[["fred","23"],["ann","27"],["bob","24"]]
```

Comment: `line.split()` doesn't do you anything, use `line.strip()` to clean it up. Wouldn't you rather use a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
with open("people.txt") as infile:
    res = []
    for name, value in zip(infile, infile):
        res.append([name.strip(), value.strip()])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['fred', '23'], ['ann', '27'], ['bob', '24']]
```

The expression:

```
for name, value in zip(infile, infile):
```

allows you to iterate in chunks of two lines over the file, as a side note you should also use a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#context-managers) to read files.

Comment: You should probably explain what's going on in `zip(*[infile]*2)` (also, wouldn't `zip(infile, infile)` do?)

Comment: This could also be put in a list comprehension, making it nice and pythonig! `res = [name.strip(), value.strip() for name, value in zip(infile, infile)]`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Is the name of the file I usually use for testing. In any case updated the answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a flat list of strings (which you will have if you replace `line.split()` with `line.strip()`), you can take 2 slices of that list with step 2 (i.e. one slice has the even-indexed elements, the other has the odd-indexed elements), then use `zip` to pair them up:

```
lines = ["Fred", "23", "Ann", "27", "Bob", "24"]
pairs = list(zip(lines[::2], lines[1::2]))
print(pairs)
```

This outputs

```
[('Fred', '23'), ('Ann', '27'), ('Bob', '24')]
```

This works beyond just file reading, but if you have a large file, it would be more performant to just read them as pairs to begin with.